# How do I parse this JSON to get the data I need?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been struggling with this and need some help.

This is a sample of the JSON that would be returned to me. I have it assigned to a variable called result, so I can test it in my code. I'm not sure how else to fake the JSON being returned to me.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10842024/JSON.js

The JSON consists of two different objects, Line and Line2, each made up of multiple path (polyline) features.

I'm trying to create a Polyline object and add each one to a map using the ESRI JavaScript API. Here is the documentation for the Polyline object:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/polyline-amd.html#polyline2

```
require(["esri/geometry/Polyline"], function(Polyline) {

  var polylineJson = {
    "paths":[[[-122.68,45.53], [-122.58,45.55],
    [-122.57,45.58],[-122.53,45.6]]],
    "spatialReference":{"wkid":4326}
  };
  var polyline = new Polyline(polylineJson);
});
```

The JSON I get returned fits what the Polyline object needs:

```
"features": [
        {
          "attributes": {
            "OBJECTID": 2368
          },
          "geometry": {
            "paths": [
              [
                [
                  -123.94500566712864,
                  45.27071700030354
                ],
                [
                  -123.9449701393585,
                  45.27069704962526
                ],
                [
                  -123.94494162013,
                  45.27067958572745
                ],
                [
                  -123.94489725722464,
                  45.2706251239781
                ],
                [
                  -123.94489153421517,
                  45.27054128625377
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
```

But how can I loop through each feature and insert the JSON into the Polyline object so that it's formatted correctly?

I know I'm missing something because I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Something in that order I guess...

```
for (var i in result.results)
{
    var features = result.results[i].features;
    for (var j in features)
    {
        console.log(features[j].attributes.OBJECTID); // print OBJECTID
        var geometry = features[j].geometry.paths;
        for (var k in geometry)
        {
            console.log(geometry[k]); // print paths, arrays of points
            var points = geometry[k];
            for (var l in points)
                console.log(points[l]); // print points
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e0dxn8ze/2/ open JavaScript console to see what goes

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested solution I just wrote.

```
// Get the JSON string
json_string = whaterver_function_gets_you_the_json();

// Parse JSON into JS
polys = JSON.parse(json_string);

// Loop through polys and create Polyline
polys.features.forEach(function(el) {
    new Polyline(el.geometry);
});
```

**Edit:** Sorry I didn't see the JSON.js link. This solution should still work, you'd just have to adjust which object property you're looping through. For instance: `result.results[0].features.forEach(function(el){});` or if you need to also loop through all the results you can just nest forEachs.